# HERE-maps CORS problems with Autocomplete

Tags: here-api

I want to use HERE maps autocomplete in my project.
But when a i send request like the one in documentation

```
this.axios.get('http://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json
  ?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}
  &app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
  &query=Pariser+1+Berl
  &beginHighlight=<b>
  &endHighlight=</b>'
  )
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

i get an error

```
OPTIONS http://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?{...} 405
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?{...}' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

In Chrome developer console in network panel i check this

```
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-auth-token, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
```

I set content-type in request headers to application/json and Provisional headers changed

```
to Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-auth-token
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
```

So if i understand right, i should set x-auth-token header. But where can i take this token?
Or may be this problem has another reason?

There's nothing about such problems in documentaion.

Comment: Can you paste all the errors logged in the browser javascript console?

Comment: OPTIONS http://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?{...} 405
Access to XMLHttpRequest at http://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?{...}' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status. Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://autocomplete.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?{} from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: We have here another example for the Autocomplete for the JS API: https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/geocoder_autocomplete

Comment: Hi Irina, did you manage to figure it out? As I am hitting this problem also. Still no response from HERE support and there is nothing in the documentation either. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was simple and a bit stupid.
When user authenticated in my app I added default header to axios

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Auth-Token'] = token
```

so this header was sended to all requests.

But HERE-map API doesn't want this header in requests and this was the cause of the problem.
The solution was to remove this header from requests to HERE-map API.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have defined by default the header :
`'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

You must deactivate it, there should not be any HttpHeaders on the call request to Here API services.

Answer (score -4):

temporary install [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) google chrome plugin .. installed then you can show top right side click on that and switch the button then refresh then again call your api and get the response.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question, but is a workaround. One that probably won't work if this code is being developed for consumption by anyone else but the author.